# отправка файлов ботом вTelegram | Aiogram

Tags: python, aiogram

При отправке файла методом
`bot.send_document(chat_id, file)`

Документ отправляется без расширения:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как я могу отправлять файлы и при этом сохранять их расширение?

Comment: а какого формата файл?

Comment: @Vadim.Sharoikin .py, но я планировал отправлять файлы любого расширения

Comment: Вот же в документации есть - https://dev-docs.aiogram.dev/api/upload_file/#upload-from-file-system

Answer (score 4):

В вашем примере нет информации о том, **как** вы готовите файл.

Как и рекомендует документация telegram, [используйте InputFile](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#inputfile) для передачи файла.

В aiogram он находится здесь:

```py
from aiogram.types import InputFile
```

При создании объекта данного класса можно указать параметр `filename`

Answer (score 1):

```
bot.send_document(chat_id, ('filename.txt', file))
```

Нужно использовать tuple в таких ситуациях

Comment: Напишите попобробнее, расскажите почему именно так

Comment: Да слушай, хер знает. Мне тоже надо было реализовать раздельно имя файла и его содержимое, при том, не загружая файл с диска. Был опыт с http запросами и выгрузкой файлов через питон, там как раз аналогичным образом отправлялись файлы...

Answer (score 0):

```
 doc = open('Имя') + '.pdf', 'rb')
 await message.reply_document(doc)
```

Указывайте имя и расширение при создании.