# aiogram как отправить файл?

Tags: python, api, telegram, бот, aiogram

на русском Stack Overflow уже есть подобный вопрос [отправка файлов ботом вTelegram | Aiogram](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1199352/%d0%be%d1%82%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%b2telegram-aiogram) . Но когда я пытаюсь вызвать `message.answer_document`, который вызывает bot.send_document, я получаю ошибку

```
future: <Task finished name='Task-6' coro=<Dispatcher._process_polling_updates() done, defined at /home/bigcubecat/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/aiogram/dispatcher/dispatcher.py:409> exception=BadRequest('Wrong http url specified')>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/bigcubecat/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/aiogram/dispatcher/dispatcher.py", line 417, in _process_polling_updates
    for responses in itertools.chain.from_iterable(await self.process_updates(updates, fast)):
  File "/home/bigcubecat/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/aiogram/dispatcher/dispatcher.py", line 238, in process_updates
    return await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
  File "/home/bigcubecat/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/aiogram/dispatcher/handler.py", line 116, in notify
    response = await handler_obj.handler(*args, **partial_data)
  File "/home/bigcubecat/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/aiogram/dispatcher/dispatcher.py", line 259, in process_update
    return await self.message_handlers.notify(update.message)
  File "/home/bigcubecat/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/aiogram/dispatcher/handler.py", line 116, in notify
    response = await handler_obj.handler(*args, **partial_data)
  File "/home/bigcubecat/__folder__/Bears/bot/handlers/bear.py", line 28, in download_document
    await message.answer_document(savepath)
  File "/home/bigcubecat/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/aiogram/types/message.py", line 688, in answer_document
    return await self.bot.send_document(
  File "/home/bigcubecat/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/aiogram/bot/bot.py", line 653, in send_document
    result = await self.request(api.Methods.SEND_DOCUMENT, payload, files)
  File "/home/bigcubecat/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/aiogram/bot/base.py", line 208, in request
    return await api.make_request(self.session, self.server, self.__token, method, data, files,
  File "/home/bigcubecat/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/aiogram/bot/api.py", line 140, in make_request
    return check_result(method, response.content_type, response.status, await response.text())
  File "/home/bigcubecat/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/aiogram/bot/api.py", line 115, in check_result
    exceptions.BadRequest.detect(description)
  File "/home/bigcubecat/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/aiogram/utils/exceptions.py", line 141, in detect
    raise cls(description)
aiogram.utils.exceptions.BadRequest: Wrong http url specified
```

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: в документацию заглядывали? может вот это вам поможет [отправка файлов](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api/#sending-files). Описаны некоторые ограничения и правила

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Нужно посылать не имя файла, как я пытался, а файл
Например:
`message.answer_document(open("file.png", "RB"))`

Answer (score 2):

```
 doc = open('Имя') + '.pdf', 'rb')
 await message.reply_document(doc)
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы.
[Постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию.
Изложите свои предложения.
Возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).
Дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit].

Answer (score 1):

Мой вариант с использованием `InputFile` из aiogram.

```
from aiogram.types import InputFile

example_path = "filename.ext" # или "folder/filename.ext"

await message.answer_photo(InputFile(path))
await message.answer_document(InputFile(path))
await message.answer_...(InputFile(path))
```